# Changing displayed rasters in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver

I loaded to CoverageStore -> ImageMosaic 3 rasters for different date. On viewing layers I need to be able select what tif I viewing now, but I do not see way to to select what I am viewing now.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the built-in OpenLayers Layer Preview has no possibility to change dimension attributes.

The only way is to use another client that is capable of changing time dimension (e.g. [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#time--elevation)) to preview the data or to add `&time=...` to the URL.

If you don't know the available times, you can find them below the corresponding Layer in the GetCapabilities XML of your GeoServer as an Interval (From/To) or as a Comma Separated List:

> http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities

```
<Dimension name="time" default="2017-08-05T23:51:31.026Z" units="ISO8601">2017-08-03T00:02:21.026Z/2017-08-05T23:51:31.026Z/PT1S</Dimension>
```

Comment: From where I should to get `time` value?

Comment: I thought you know that when you added them ... I updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

The layer preview is designed for a quick check on your data. To choose which tif is to be returned you need to use the `TIME` dimension in your client. See this [manual page](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) that describes what to do.